# Resolved URL bookmark (iCloud file) stops working after a few days: no such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm reading a file using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`:

```swift
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    guard let url = urls.first else {
        return
    }
    openDocument(at: url) { result in
        if let .success(data) = result {
            save(url)
        }
    }
}

func openDocument(at url: URL, completion: (Result<Data, LoadError>) -> Void) {
     if startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            defer { stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: self)
                return .success(data)
            } catch {
                return .failure(.genericError(error))
            }
        }
        return .failure(.noAccess)
}
```

So after reading the document I make a copy of the `bookmarkData` of its URL:

```swift
func save(_ url: URL) {
    NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { coorindatedURL in
        if coorindatedURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            defer { coorindatedURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
            do {
                let bookmarkData = try coorindatedURL.bookmarkData()
                // save bookmarkData with the url
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then every time I read the document I read from saved `bookmarkData`:

```swift
 var stale = false
if let url = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale), stale == false {
    if startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
        defer { stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

It works at first, and for 1 or 2 days, but after a few days I started getting this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file FILENAME couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/PATH/TO/FILE.doc, NSUnderlyingError=0x2830cae80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I checked the file is still there in my iCloud folder, and the `stale` flag is false. So I'm not sure what the problem is?

Thanks!